# Display Map like OpenStreetMap

Tags: postgis, openlayers, openstreetmap, geoserver

I like the way OpenStreetMap display its map. It almost looks like Google Map. I have already installed GeoServer and PostGis on my notebook. I also got [this cloudmade osm file](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/asia/indonesia#downloads_breadcrumbs) for my country, Indonesia. I downloaded indonesia.osm.bz2.

I successfully imported it into my PostGis and did setup it on my GeoServer but it didn't display map same like OpenStreetMap. I chose planet_osm_polygon as my layer in GeoServer. At the end, I got this one displayed with openlayers.
[alt text http://deerawan.com/blogimages/map_polygon.jpg](http://deerawan.com/blogimages/map_polygon.jpg)

But I expected to be like this one
[alt text http://deerawan.com/blogimages/map-indo.png](http://deerawan.com/blogimages/map-indo.png)

was it wrong OSM file that I used from Cloudmade?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/) from Geoserver blog.

There you'll find a step by step guide on how to setup OSM data, including database import, styling, etc.

Comment: Thank you igorti for your reply, I actually have seen this tutorial as well. But the main problem is I have to download almost 10GB planet file. Unfortunately, my country internet speed is terrible. When I found Indonesia OSM on cloudmade I was so happy. I thought I can achieve same map like OpenStreetMap without using planet file. Anyway, have you ever used planet file?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I should definetely give it a try!

There should be no difference between using whole planet or just certain country. Did you follow the guide above step-by-step and it's not wotking?

Comment: Yeah, the result was not as I expected. I'm afraid that I missed steps from the tutorial above.

Comment: You can download smaller planet files for particular regions at: http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/ for you, this would mean ~200Mb for australia-oceania, perhaps that is a better starting point?

Answer (score 4):

The file you download contains just data.
No information about the way it's displayed…

You got 2 solutions:
- Use OSM directly in your map with a OpenLayers.Layer.OSM ( http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm.html ),
- Use a cartographic server to style your data the way you want… (OSM uses mapnik, or you can use mapserver : http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmData , no idea if they're available styles for geoserver )

HTH,

Comment: Thank you tonio for your reply. Hmm, is osm file only contains data, tonio? I can't use osm layer because I want to use the map offline (no internet connection). So that, I have to build my own map server. Is there a result screenshot from the second link (mapserver/wiki) you gave me?

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer requires two things to render a map:

**data**

Just importing the OSM planet dump isn't enough to get a nice map, you need more than just roads and landmarks.  OpenStreetMap adds a coastline dataset (which I think is actually derived from OpenStreetMap data, but pre-processed a bit for performance reasons) and some data from the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) project.

**stylesheets**

GeoServer uses the [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) [SLD](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) format for styles, so you'll need to find or create some SLD styles specific to the OpenStreetMap dataset.  Here are a few suggestions of places you could look for them:

- [OpenStreetMap SLDs](http://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld) used on the [OpenGeo OSM demo](http://maps.opengeo.org/osm/)
- [OpenStreetMap in a box](http://dev.ifs.hsr.ch/osminabox/wiki) also includes some tools for keeping OpenStreetMap data up-to-date
- [OpenStreetMap tutorial](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/) on the GeoServer blog

I'm also working on a [tool to convert Mapnik map files](http://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools/) to GeoServer configurations.  It works okay with the styles from [MapQuest Open](http://open.mapquest.co.uk/) but still has some issues with the ones used for openstreetmap.org.  If you want to give it a try though, bug reports are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the coastlines and world boundaries. There is more information on the [osm wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik#Datasets) about where to download the additional data to draw the coastlines.